# How do you do conditional "left join" in R?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, left-join

I have found myself doing a "conditional left join" several times in R. To illustrate with an example; if you have two data frames such as:

```
> df
    a b
  1 1 0
  2 2 0

> other.df
    a b
  1 2 3
```

The goal is to end up with this data frame:

```
> final.df
    a b
  1 1 0
  2 2 3
```

The code I've been written so far:

```
c <- merge(df, other.df, by=c("a"), all.x = TRUE)
c[is.na(c$b.y),]$b.y <- 0
d<-subset(c, select=c("a","b.y"))
colnames(d)[2]<-b
```

to finally arrive with the result I wanted.

Doing this in effectively four lines makes the code very opaque.
Is there any better, less cumbersome way to do this?

Comment: I was going to recommend the **sqldf** package if you'd like to do more complicated SQL type stuff on data frames, but as usual when I tried to fire it up to write an answer it kept crashing R. So...you know...maybe you'll have better luck. But it's never been reliable for me.

Comment: @joran, Suggest you read the `Troubleshooting` section on the sqldf home page (http://sqldf.googlecode.com/#Troubleshooting).

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Oh, I have read that. I tried everything in FAQ#5, and it still crashes R. :(

Comment: @Joran, Since the package is widely used and no one else has ever reported this I suggest you send me a more specific report of precisely what you did and what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways.  In both cases the first line does a left merge returning the required columns.  In the case of `merge` we then have to set the names.  The final line in both lines replaces `NA`s with `0`.

**merge**

```
res1 <- merge(df, other.df, by = "a", all.x = TRUE)[-2]
names(res1) <- names(df)
res1[is.na(res1)] <- 0
```

**sqldf**

```
library(sqldf)
res2 <- sqldf("select a, o.b from df left join 'other.df' o using(a)")
res2[is.na(res2)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In two lines:

```
c <- merge(df, other.df,all=T)
c=c[which(!duplicated(c$a)),]
```

So this takes the values from both data sets and omits rows with id duplicates from the second. I am not sure which is left and which is right, so if you want the other: flip the data upside down and do the same thing.

```
c=c[length(c$a):1,]
c=c[which(!duplicated(c$a)),]
```