# Staggered join / new grouping / join in R with data.table's X[Y] syntax

Tags: r, data.table

I have two `data.tables`: `samples, resources`

`resources` is connected with `samples` via `primary` and `secondary` ids.
I want to combine the information from the resources with the sample-table first via the primary id, and only if this produces NA, then I want to resort to the secondary resources from the same table (within one data.table command chain).

```
# resources:
   primary secondary info
1:      17        42  "I"
2:      18        NA  "J"
3:      19        43  "K"

# samples:
   name primary secondary
1:  "a"      17        55
2:  "b"       0        42
3   "c"      18        42
```

The desired result would be:

```
# joined tables:
   name info  # primary secondary
1:  "a"  "I"
2:  "b"  "I"
3:  "c"  "J"
```

The first join via `primary` is easy, it produces

```
# Update:
samples <- data.table(name = letters[1:3], 
                      primary = c(17, 0, 18), 
                      secondary = c(55, 42, 42))
resources <- data.table(primary = 17:19, 
                        secondary = c(42, NA, 43), 
                        info = LETTERS[9:11])
# first join:
setkey(samples, primary)
setkey(resources, primary)
samples[resources]

   name info  # primary secondary
1:  "a"  "I"
2:  "b"   NA
3:  "c"  "J"
```

But then? I need to re-key samples with `setkey(samples, secondary)`, right? And then subset to only those rows that produces NAs. But all this is not really possible within one command chain (and imagine there were more than two criteria...). How can I achieve this more succinctly?

... updated with code for the data.tables.

Comment: Perhaps make easily reproducible by including code that constructs `samples` and `resources`?

Comment: not `data.table` friendly but just in case it is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369837/how-do-you-do-conditional-left-join-in-r

Comment: wanting to do it in one command chain is misguided

Comment: @eddi -- Yes indeed. I think that's a key observation.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien you may read the comments under eddi answer. Maybe you can recommend some alternative code organization in mentioned case? I always like to improve my code.

Comment: @JanGorecki -- Sounds like you've got a regular idiom that works well for you, so I'd suggest you just stick with that! I happen to find the 'smaller chunks' approach easier to parse --- but only because I'm more used to it, and see no *inherent* virtue in getting everything on a single, possibly very long, line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you could do it on a single line, I think that obscures the meaning of what you do, makes things incredibly hard to read/understand/debug/remember what the hell you did in a month, and is simply a bad idea.

Smaller, much more easily digestible chunks are the way to go imo:

```
setkey(samples, primary)
setkey(resources, primary)
samples[resources, info := i.info]

setkey(samples, secondary)
setkey(resources, secondary)
samples[resources, info := ifelse(is.na(info), i.info, info)]

samples
#   name primary secondary info
#1:    b       0        42    I
#2:    c      18        42    J
#3:    a      17        55    I

# keep going with tertiary and so on if you like
```

As @nachti pointed out in the comments, you might need to add `allow.cartesian=TRUE` for versions before 1.9.5 depending on your data.

Comment: I get that's it's cool, when you first discover chaining/piping, to just do a ton of things on one line, but after that initial excitement wears off, you need to scale back and realize that you don't actually want your entire script on a single line.

Comment: You have to add `by = .EACHI` since dt 1.9.4: `samples[resources, info := ifelse(is.na(info), i.info, info), by = .EACHI]`  For more information see https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @nachti no, that's incorrect - the above was run using 1.9.5 (the "have to" part is incorrect - you *can* add it, but that won't change the result and it may or may not result in a performance difference - I'm not sure which way it'll go)

Comment: in 1.9.4 i get   Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin) NULL else as.integer(max(nrow(x),  : 
  Join results in 4 rows; more than 3 = max(nrow(x),nrow(i)). Check for duplicate key values in i, each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try including `j` and dropping `by` (by-without-by) so that j runs for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice.

Comment: Ah, right, I forgot that 1.9.5 fixed some spurious error messages from earlier. Like that message says, simply add `allow.cartesian = TRUE` in 1.9.4- (you don't need to do it anymore).

Comment: Good point @eddi! `allow.cartesian = TRUE` is nearly twice as fast as `by = .EACHI`. See also https://github.com/nachti/datatable_test/blob/master/staggered_join.R for a benchmark.

Comment: @eddi I also like the clean code, but in my case I see nothing more difficult in reading long data.table chains than splitting them into multiple queries. Maybe it is something from SQL where I used to long 10+ [Common Table Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression). Besides of clean code I prefer to have code which is *conceptually clean* where single query on a table can be written as single query. This makes it easier to read the chains for me.

Comment: @JanGorecki I suggest the following experiment - set a reminder to come back to this question in 1 month, then read both this answer and yours and time how long it takes you to understand each. Shock me and tell me that this one doesn't take you at least 2x less time to understand :)

Comment: @eddi Already had many such experiments, some even on the queries I wrote 1y+ ago. Still prefer to have them organized into conceptual queries. If you consider you have a process of 50+ chains in your code, and then split each of them into multiple single commands you may find it harder to understand than if they would be organized into conceptual chains.

Comment: @eddi what is the ping about? Did you seen [this](https://github.com/jangorecki/dtq)? chaining is awesome :P

Comment: @jangorecki just had a reminder set for this :) I haven't used it, but looks pretty cool - I can see it coming in very handy for debugging complicated expressions.

Answer (score 2):

This would be one chain with 2 calls to `resources`, one of them re-setkey behind the scene.

```
library(data.table)
samples <- data.table(name = letters[1:3], 
                      primary = c(17, 0, 18), 
                      secondary = c(55, 42, 42))
resources <- data.table(primary = 17:19, 
                        secondary = c(42, NA, 43), 
                        info = LETTERS[9:11])
setkey(samples, primary)
setkey(resources, primary)
samples[resources, info := i.info
        ][, .(name, info),, secondary
          ][resources[, info,, secondary], info := ifelse(is.na(info), i.info, info)
            ][, secondary := NULL]
```

As you are asking about more complicated examples. It's worth to note the data.table queries can be easily managed as modules by preparing sub-query arguments in advance. They can be later easily conditionally managed. See below example.

```
lkp2 <- quote(resources[, info,, secondary])
lkp2_formula <- quote(info := ifelse(is.na(info), i.info, info))
setkey(samples, primary)
samples[resources, info := i.info
        ][, .(name, info),, secondary
          ][eval(lkp2), eval(lkp2_formula)
            ][, secondary := NULL]
```

If you heavily rely on data.table chaining processes you may find [dtq](https://github.com/jangorecki/dtq) package useful.

Comment: I like the suggestion to predefine the `i` and the `j` commands separately, this might help keep the code easier to read in more complicated cases. I will combine this strategy with the suggestions from @eddi and @nachti.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's too tricky to do it within one command chain, but I've a solution for you:

```
### First step
samples[resources[samples, nomatch = 0], info := info]
samples

   name primary secondary info
1:    b       0        42   NA
2:    a      17        55    I
3:    c      18        42    J

### Second step
setkey(samples, secondary)
setkey(resources, secondary)
## create new column info1
samples[resources[samples[is.na(info)],
                  list(info1 = unique(info)), by = .EACHI],
        info1 := info1]
## merge it to samples, where info is NA
samples[is.na(info), info := info1]
## remove info1 (and maybe other unused columns)
samples[, info1 := NULL]
## sort samples by name
setkey(samples, name)
samples

   name primary secondary info
1:    a      17        55    I
2:    b       0        42    I
3:    c      18        42    J
```

HTH
~g